# Matlab random vs np.randn

Tags: python, matlab, random, numpy

i am trying a  piece of code in python its giving wrong result.i just want to confirm that np.randn function is same as Matlab randn
plzz helppp

```
S=[ 3.+3.j  1.-3.j -3.+1.j  1.+3.j  1.-1.j]
SNR=arange(6,23,1)

BER=zeros(len(SNR))  
Es=10


for ii in arange(0,len(SNR)):

  variance=Es*(10**(-SNR[ii]/10))
  std_dev=cmath.sqrt(variance/2)
  noise=(np.random.randn(len(S))+cmath.sqrt(-1)*np.random.randn(len(S))) *std_dev
  S_noisy=S+noise


print(noise)
```

matlab code

```
SNR=6:22;
display(SNR)
display(length(SNR))
BER=zeros(1,length(SNR));

display(BER)
display(length(BER))
Es=10;


for ii=1:length(SNR)
   variance=Es*10^(-SNR(ii)/10);
   std_dev=sqrt(variance/2);
   noise=(randn(1,length(S))+sqrt(-1)*randn(1,length(S)))*std_dev;
   S_noisy=S+noise;


end

display(noise)
```

result should be

```
 [0.1150 + 0.1889i  -0.0756 + 0.2055i   0.1862 + 0.0094i   0.1174 - 0.2288i

0.4456 - 0.0659i]
```

Comment: if i add the exact noisy sequence generated in matlab even then it doesnot give the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

NumPy's `np.random.randn` returns samples from a standard normal distribution. The result won't be the same from run to run. You could get reproducible results by setting the seed:

```
np.random.seed(123)
```

But this will not necessarily produce the same result as the one you are getting from Matlab. Matlab uses its own random number generator, and as far as I know, there is no way to synchronize Matlab's random numbers with NumPy's.

If you want the exact same results, save the random numbers generated by Matlab into a file, then load those numbers into NumPy.

Comment: what should i use to get same results

Comment: You could write your own random number generator and implement it in MATLAB and Python.

Comment: Or you could run the code in one of the two platforms (Matlab or python) and record the numbers generated in that run to be used with the other platform. But this is not so efficient.

The danger with coding your own (pseudo)random number generator is to introduce a bias without being aware of it.